# How to set nginx cache headers to never expire?

Tags: caching, nginx, http-headers

Right now I'm using this:

```
location ~* \.(js|css)$ { # |png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico
  expires max;
  #log_not_found off; # what's this for?
}
```

And this is what I see in firebug:

[image]

Did it work? If I didn't get it wrong, my browser is asking for the file again, and nginx is answering 'not modified', so my browser uses the cache. But I thought the browser shouldn't even ask for the file, it already knows it will never expire.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use F5 to reload the page. Use click on the url + enter, or click in a link. That's how I got only 1 request.

Comment: but how can be cache a file for even F5 or refresh button click?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly , your file is not stale as its max-age and expiry date are still valid and hence the browser will not communicate with server.The Browser doesn't ask for the file unless it is stale. i.e. its cache-control ( max -age) is over or Expiry date is gone. In that case it will ask the serve if the given copy is still valid or not. if yes, it will serve same copy, else it will get new one.

Update :

See, here is the thing. F5/refresh will always make browser to request the server if anything is modified or not. It will have If-Modified-Since in Request header. While it is different from just navigating the site, coming back to pages and click events in which browser will not ask server , and load from cache silently( no server call). Also, if you are testing on firefox Live HTTP Headers, it will show you exactly what is requested, while Firebug will always show you If-Modified-Since. Safari's developer menu should show load time as 0. Hope it helps.

Comment: Then why did my browser issue that 'GET all.css' request? I don't want the browser to check whether the file has been modified or not. I want to avoid that unnecessary request. Is that possible?